# Two classes with same name in classpath

Tags: java, classpath

If I have two classes with same name say Matcher.java in two different jar in my classpath which one will be picked up by JVM , is there anyway I can suggest JVM to pick a specific one ?

Comment: While this issue has well-defined behavior, please tell me that you will never have such a naming conflict yourself. Packages exist for reasons, right?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9757720/2757620) might be helpful to look at

Answer (score 19):

Quoting [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html):

> Specification order
>
> The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is
>   important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the
>   directories in the order they appear in the class path variable. In
>   the example above, the Java interpreter will first look for a needed
>   class in the directory C:\java\MyClasses. Only if it doesn't find a
>   class with the proper name in that directory will the interpreter look
>   in the C:\java\OtherClasses directory.

The example mentioned:

> C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses ...

So yes, it will load the one appears in the classpath that specified first.

Comment: What if we use the wildcard? E.g.  `java -cp C:\java\*` ? Then will it first look at `C:\java\A.jar` or `C:\java\B.jar` or is it unspecified behavior?

Comment: Is there any chance that class from second jar file may possibly be loaded. Actually I want to avoid that, but I am not certain. There might be a case when the class may be loaded from second jar file as well?

Comment: @Pacerier cannot use wildcards to specify jars not sure if it will consider C:\java\* as C:\java to look for class files. Bottom line only directories and jar files can be used in classpath.

Answer (score 3):

The first one found in the classpath. ie, the first jar containing your class will be used.

You can't control it from within the JVM, but you *can* control the classpath - make sure the one you want is listed/found first in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

there is a way for you to specify where the class should be picked from.. you can create your own class loader which would load classes according to your requirement.

you can use your class loaded in 2 ways

1. Pass it as a parameter to jvm (`java -Djava.system.class.loader
   =com.somepackage.YourCustomClassLoader com.somepackage.YourMainClass`)
2. Use the class loader programatically to load a specific class (refer the links provided).

here are some useful links on class loading

- [Oracle - How to write your own class loader](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Security/Fundamentals/magercises/ClassLoader/help.html)
- [A very nice post on    writing custom class loader](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-write-custom-class-loader-to.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified path of the class when using it.  But if you mean the class with the same name also has the same package - fix the class-path.

Comment: The problem is that how do you know about this, if you are using a third party jar files! anyway to figure this out?

Comment: @qartal A Jar is just a specialized Zip file. Make a copy of the Jar, rename it from .jar to .zip, and it should be easy to inspect what is inside, and where. The JDK also provides the jar tool that has options for listing Jar content.