# How JVM works when two same jar be included in classpath

Tags: java

It was a mistake of my co-worker:  there was a jar named test.jar and he has fixed a bug of it.  Then he re-compile the code and built a new jar named testnew.jar
The problem was he put these two jar into one folder which in classpath.
So when program was running, the behavior was a kind of mess.  I didn't know what had happened but after removing test.jar, everthing was fine again.

So I'm wondering what's the behavior of JVM.  Does it use the class file in first jar it meet?  Or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, by default it uses classes from first jar. That's why you have to check library directory for duplicates. Happend so many times for me and my colleagues.

Comment: So seems there's no machanism to avoid this.

Comment: This is an interesting *supposition*, but do you have any reference to back it up?

Comment: @XiaoYao The way to avoid this is to not add the same thing twice.  If you duplicate the same thing it has a defined behaviour so it doesn't have to be a problem.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this comes under the heading "Undefined Behavior". Remember that not everyone is using the SUN JVM, and even if they were you cant rely on every version being the same!  I believe the only thing official is that once it has found a class (or not found it) it will not check a second time, even if you add jar files at runtime.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just my experience. People often forget about it.

Comment: Then you *cannot* rely on it. As far as I can tell, it's undefined and undocumented behavior except for the `java` tool itself (which documents its search plan).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, it isn't defined.

Java has a pluggable classloader system, and thus the only way to know what will happen is to look at the documentation of the [`ClassLoader` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), probably in particular the [`ClassLoader#findClass` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findClass%28java.lang.String%29), which doesn't define a behavior for this, and to look at the relevant sections of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) and [JVM specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3), neither of which seem to specify a constraint on class loaders in this regard. Thus, unless the behavior is documented by the class loader being used by your web container, you can't know for certain which class will be loaded.

The *odds are* that the first one found that matches the binary name of the class will be the one loaded, but there's a **big** difference between behavior we suppose to be the case, and behavior that is specified and/or documented.

Comment: I found [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html) in the java docs. See the section "How the Java Launcher Finds JAR-class-path Classes"....I think it says that _The JAR files that appear in the JAR-class-path are searched after any earlier class path entries, and before any entries that appear later in the class path._......so don't you think that will be the default behavior to look into the classpath ???..

Comment: @ShashankKadne: Good deal, so that tells you what the `java` tool (the Java launcher) does (at least, what it did back in v1.4.2, ~10 years ago; but I doubt it's changed). Which is useful for when you use the `java` tool. It does **not** tell you, generally, what classloaders will do. The OP didn't say what kind of application it was (desktop application started via `java`, web application where the class loader is defined by the container, etc.).

Comment: @ShashankKadne I believe your link is no longer found, so adding updated one here.. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

If there are duplicates, it reads the one which appears first in your classpath.

**Edit**
A classpath file in general looks something like this..

```
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Temp/test.jar"/>
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Temp/testnew.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

If your classpath looks something like above, then your JVM will look into test.jar first, as it appears first in the classpath. If you want to test it on your own, try moving the classpathentry for testnew.jar above the entry of test.jar. You will see that it now refers testnew.jar instead of test.jar.

Reference: [FindingClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html)

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : well, I don't have a written proof saying that, but I have tested it on my own. That was the default behavior I observed. See my edit above, I did something similar to prove it.

Comment: `@Shashank`: Then you *cannot* trust the behavior, it can vary by classloader, or even within uses of the same classloader if it's using some weird lookup methodology. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

JVM loads whatever specific JARs are on the classpath. Since java 6 there has also been a wildcard notation. Below are a couple of examples.

```
java -cp ".:lib/example.jar" Main
```

The above will only load classes found in the current directory and inside example.jar. Whereas the next example will use any jar to load classes from.

```
java -cp ".:lib/*" Main
```

I don't think the order for which jar in a directory is examined first to find a class is defined, just which ever order the OS gave when listing the files.

It is likely your IDE (or whatever you're using to run your program) is using the latter notation to run your program. You could change it so that is uses the former, though it will break if you ever change the name of a jar or add new ones.